# How do I handle complex JSON information inside a CSV file?

Tags: blazor, syncfusion, csvhelper, csv-import

I´m trying to create an import of CSV data into my Blazor project in .NET7 but I´m facing issues with how to handle the data on one specific field in the CSV and can´t seem to get around the issue.

The CSV data I´m trying to import typically looks like this:
First there are columnHeaders for "Name", "Address", "City" etc. and finally "Notes".
Then comes the data values using ; as the delimiter.
I´m able to read in all fields except "Notes" because it has a different format

```
NameValue;AddressValue;CityValue;"{
  "Information": "",
  "InformationHistoryFixed": "",
  "customerNotes": [],
  "bookingNotes": []
}"
```

The only thing in the "Notes" header I manage to use from this is the very first "{ then comes a row break that cuts me off from the rest of the data.

Right now I´m using an InputFile through a file uploader/picker I then run a method to process the data which is where the headers are assigned and the rest of the data is sent to a DataTable to read values in each cell.

```
private async Task ProcessImportData()
{
    if (uploadedFileStream != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await uploadedFileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
            {
                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
                application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Xlsx;

                using (Stream inputStream = memoryStream)
                {
                    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream);
                    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    
                    columnHeaders = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet.UsedRange.LastColumn; i++)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet[1, i]?.Text))
                        {                                
                            string[] headers = worksheet[1, i].Text.Split(';');                                
                            foreach (string header in headers)
                            {
                                columnHeaders.Add(header.Trim());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    foreach (var columnHeader in columnHeaders)
                    {
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(columnHeader);
                    }

                    for (int i = 2; i <= worksheet.UsedRange.LastRow; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                        for (int j = 1; j <= worksheet.UsedRange.LastColumn; j++)
                        {
                            dataRow[j - 1] = worksheet[i, j].Text;
                        }
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }

                    string jsonString = GetJsonStringFromWorksheet(worksheet);

                    ProcessDataTable(dataTable);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It then goes to ProcessDataTable where it should create a model and fill in Name, Address, Notes etc:

```
private void ProcessDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    processedData = new List<ImportCustomerModel>();

    // Loop through each row in the DataTable, skipping the first row with column headers
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[i];
        ImportCustomerModel model = new ImportCustomerModel();

        string line = row[0].ToString();           

        if (columns.Length >= 21)
        {            
            model.Name= columns[0]?.Trim();
            model.Address= columns[1]?.Trim();
            model.City= columns[2]?.Trim();
            ....
            model.Notes= columns[20]?.Trim();
          
            processedData.Add(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. That's not a CSV with a JSON field, that's a badly formatted text file that no parser can read. The code you posted has nothing to do with either JSON or CSV either, it's trying to read an Excel file. Excel files aren't CSVs, they're ZIP packages containing XML files. It doesn't matter what a cell contains, to Excel it's just text or a number

Comment: Where does this completely custom format come from? Can you change the code that produces this to use a better suited, common format? If the format is created by some commercial package, do they have client libraries? Alternatives? Frankly, I seriously doubt *any* company would produce this text because they wouldn't be able to read it themselves

Comment: The CSV files are created by a common company as their custom export file so I don´t have any power of how it is formatted I´m afraid. The code I have used is used to read the cells in Excel form true, do you know of a better way of handling it? Thank you for your reply

Comment: I understand that you have a json with linebreaks as a header. Not very common but this is what you have. As you can detect the beginning of the json "{" you can detect also the end. As i can understand, the end of the json would be in another datarow as there are line breaks, so you have to use a flag to skip the rest of the code until you detect the end of the json.

Comment: If the file was a csv, your issue will remain, as the json field will be splited into several lines.

Comment: The header is just "Notes;" but then the different rows in the JSON part of the file interepts with the reading of headers and values. entering the CSV file and removing the line breaks solves the issue, but it´s not a feasible solution for big files. But I haven´t managed to remove the line breaks within the "{ ... }" using code.

Comment: @Erucio is the file a an Excel or CSV file? CSV isn't an Excel format, it's just text Values with Separators usually Commas. Excel has no delimiters and no problem handling such complex strings. No CSV parser can handle this text though. CSV allows newlines and delimiters in quoted fields BUT the quoted value in your sample is `"{
  "`. The quotes *must* match. Any quotes inside the quoted field would require some form of custom escaping. That's why I said whoever produces this file won't be able to read it themselves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The file properties says: Microsoft Excel-file with comma seperated values (.csv) So it should be a CSV file, but yes it opens great in Excel and puts the entire Notes JSON string inside the same cell. opening it up in notebook for example displays the header row as row 1, then the values up until "{ as row 2 and then it breaks down the JSON into multiple new rows

Comment: So it's not an Excel file at all, even though Excel is the application registered to load it. It's not CSV at all, it violates the standard. You *assume* it is, only because Excel was somehow able to *import* it as a text file. You'll have to reproduce the same techniques Excel used to do that. You'll have to write code that looks for `"{` or `"[` after the end of the previous field and starts processing the rest of the text stream as JSON. You may be able to "just" read text until you encounter `}"` or `]"`. No CSV parser will do that though, and certainly not CsvHelper

Comment: You *could* include JSON in CSV files if the quote character wasn't `"` and the JSON string wasn't indented (ie no newlines). Any CSV parser would just return the JSON content as a text value. If you're sure you won't find the field separator (`;` or `,`) in the JSON text, you could risk not using quotes. That's not the case with this file though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I have been trying to create a method for flattening or reading just the data between "{ and }" but haven´t had much luck since the reader cannot find the "} within the same row. So I´ve also tried a method that stringifies the entire file so it reads the entire data with linebreaks and all, but I´m having a hard time manipulating the data this way instead.

Comment: Perhaps the best appoarch would be to write a method that removes the " quotes if they are outside of a JSON string, making the JSON section readable and perhaps making it able to be flattened into a single row, then returned to the same datacell.

Comment: According to [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) it is OK for CSV cells to include a carriage return or line feed, but when they do they need to be enclosed in double quotes.  The real problem is that the embedded JSON is also using quotes -- and those are not properly escaped as per [RFC 4180 §2.7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2): *If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.*

Comment: Given that your text file explicitly violates this requirement of RFC 4180 you can't use a CSV reader to parse it.  Try contacting the vendor to explain the problem to them, and ask them for documentation for the format.  In particular you need to know how  semicolon and double quote characters will be escaped when they appear in both non-JSON and JSON cells.

Comment: That is going to be a tough one.  My version of Excel, version 2402, can't read that properly. It also breaks the lines after the first `"{` just like CsvHelper does.  If I manually put the JSON into one field and then save it as CSV from Excel, it properly escapes the inner double quotes with another double quote.

Comment: @Erucio the best approach is to tell whoever produced this they have a bug, or ask them for support. This format is so mind-bogglingly wrong though, I suspect there's a configuration issue somewhere. Perhaps someone stored JSON text in a text column and exported the CSV forgetting to set the `text quote` setting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I´ve solved the issue by stringifying the entire file, and then setting requirements for where the linebreaks should be i.e. after each closing note bracket }"
this lets me read the string just like a CSV should be formatted, where all values for the header columns are available on one row separated by ";" in my case. Then jumping to the next row after the last bit of data is found for that row, which is always }" in my case. Not pretty, but those are the data files I´ve been handed. Thank you for all your help, perspective and experience!

Comment: What do you mean "stringify"? The file is already a string so how are you modifying it? If you use `"}\n` as a row delimiter and disable field quoting you'll be able to read it with any library **unless** one of the JSON fields contains `;`. In that case the delimiter will try to treat the `Notes` field as multiple ones. That's why I didn't propose this

Comment: I import the file as a worksheet so I can take the headers that are properly set on row 1, then I flatten the rest of the string and run the "new row" logic after the }". I could make it so that while within brackets {} the delimiter ; is ignored but the JSON fields shouldn´t contain any ;